# how to refresh the values of a tile without reload the whole model?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, sap-cloud-platform

I am new in SAPui5 and I have an issue about to refresh the value of tiles in SAPui5. As we know we can use the `model.refresh(true)`, but it will rendering the model and cause a flickered.

Is there another way to refresh the value without to refresh the model?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Your View:

```
<Text id="myTextControl" text="{myBindingText}" />
```

Your Controller:

```
this.getView().byId("myTextControl").getBinding("<BINDED_PROPERTY>").refresh(); //In this case the binded property is "text"
```

Comment: thanks alexP, that's working, but that's cause flickered also, i do dynamics binding on my view.xml, is it problem with my view.xml?